# Corrupted data in vertex shader attribute location

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-array

My model looks stretched because of corrupted data in vertex shader attribute location

Here's the vertex shader code:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 boneWeigths;
layout (location = 4) in ivec4 boneIDs;

out vec3 vNormal;
out vec3 fragPos;
out vec2 fragTexCoord;

const int MAX_BONES = 100;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 boneTransforms[MAX_BONES];

void main()
{
    mat4 boneTx = boneTransforms[boneIDs[0]] * boneWeigths[0]
                + boneTransforms[boneIDs[1]] * boneWeigths[1]
                + boneTransforms[boneIDs[2]] * boneWeigths[2]
                + boneTransforms[boneIDs[3]] * boneWeigths[3];
    vec4 pos = boneTx * vec4(vertPos, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = MVP * pos;
    vec4 normal = boneTx * vec4(vertNormal, 0.0f);
    vNormal = normalize(vec3(M * normal));
    fragPos = vec3(M * pos);
    fragTexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, texCoord.y);
}
```

The problem seems to be **corrupted data in boneIDs** (boneIDs data is fine on CPU, but getting corrupted data in shader). I tried hard-coding boneIDs data in shader, and that works fine.

Here's the code for VAO:

```
    // create buffers/arrays
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    // load data into vertex buffers
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    unsigned int sz = sizeof(BoneVertex);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(BoneVertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // set the vertex attribute pointers
    // vertex Positions
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(BoneVertex), (void*)0);
    // vertex normals
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(BoneVertex), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    // vertex texture coords
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(BoneVertex), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    // bone weights
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(BoneVertex), (void*)(8 * sizeof(float)));
    // bone ids
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(BoneVertex), (void*)(12 * sizeof(float)));

    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

BoneVertex structure:

```
struct BoneVertex
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 normal;
    glm::vec2 textureCoords;
    glm::vec4 boneWeights;
    glm::ivec4 boneIDs;
}
```

This is weird, because the first 3 attributes data seems fine. The problem is with boneIDs and boneWeights
Is this somehow related to padding, and how data is arranged in a structure? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boneIDs` is a vertex shader input with an integral data type:

> ```c
> layout (location = 4) in ivec4 boneIDs;
> ```

If you want to specify the generic vertex attribute data for an integral attribute, then you have to use `glVertexAttribIPointer` (focus on `I`) rather than `glVertexAttribPointer` (see [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)).
Note, the type argument doesn't specify the type of the target attribute, it specifies the element type of the source data array. `glVertexAttribPointer` converts the source data array to floating point values, but `glVertexAttribIPointer` specifies the array for integral target attributes.

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(BoneVertex), (void*)(12 * sizeof(float)));`</s>

```cpp
glVertexAttribIPointer(4, 4, GL_INT, sizeof(BoneVertex), (void*)(12 * sizeof(float)));
```